# How to convert mixed datetime formats into single one in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I am working with DataFrame which contains multiple datetime formats in one column. For example:

```
2020-11-09 00:00:48
2020-11-09 00:00:48
2020-11-09 00:00:48
2020-11-09 00:00:48
2020-11-09 00:00:48
2020-08-25
2020-08-25
2017-08-25
2018-08-25
2020-08-25
25.08.2020
25.08.2020  
25.08.2017
25.08.2018  
25.08.2020
```

I want to convert it into "dd.mm.yyyy" format.
`pd.to_datetime(columnName, format = "dd.mm.yyyy")` does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

date_list = ["2020-11-09 00:00:48",
"2020-11-09 00:00:48",
"2020-11-09 00:00:48",
"2020-11-09 00:00:48",
"2020-11-09 00:00:48",
"2020-08-25",
"2020-08-25",
"2017-08-25",
"2018-08-25",
"2020-08-25",
"25.08.2020",
"25.08.2020",  
"25.08.2017",
"25.08.2018",  
"25.08.2020"]

df = pd.DataFrame(date_list,columns=['date'])  
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

output will be

```
    date
0   09/11/2020
1   09/11/2020
2   09/11/2020
3   09/11/2020
4   09/11/2020
5   25/08/2020
6   25/08/2020
7   25/08/2017
8   25/08/2018
9   25/08/2020
10  25/08/2020
11  25/08/2020
12  25/08/2017
13  25/08/2018
14  25/08/2020
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, I got an error with `NaT` values. `NaTType does not support strftime`. I forgot to consider that my dataset contains NaN values. Can you help with this?

Comment: You can replace NaN value in the column  by `df['date'] = df['date'].fillna(0)` then `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y') if x != 0 else x)` And you need to do handle the zero entry in the date column according to your requirement

Answer (score 3):

You can use pd.to_datetime(data,'infer_datetime_format=True'):

Create the dataframe with your data:

```
data = {'dates': ['2020-11-09 00:00:48' ,'2020-11-09 00:00:48',
                  '2020-11-09 00:00:48' ,'2020-11-09 00:00:48',
                  '2020-11-09 00:00:48' ,'2020-08-25',
                  '2020-08-25' ,'2017-08-25',
                  '2018-08-25' ,'2020-08-25',
                  '25.08.2020' ,'25.08.2020',
                  '25.08.2017' ,'25.08.2018',
                  '25.08.2020']}
mini_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Convert it to the same datetime format.

```
mini_df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(mini_df['dates'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Result dataframe:
[image: result:]